# firebase realtimedatabase not updating online

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just setup a firebase realtime database that has JSON `[Continent:{key:"old"}]` But, it never changes how ever I try.

Here's my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseDatabase db;
    DatabaseReference ref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        ref = db.getReference("Continent");

        ref.child("key").setValue("The new value");
    }
}
```

I've set the security rules like

```
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
```

when I check the value on the phone, it does say it changed to "The new value" but on the database, it stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

After a full annoying day,

I just found out my emulator internet wasn't working, tried to fix it many ways and failed, and finally Cold Booted it, and worked fine.

[image]